# Is there a way to just create Typescript declaration (.d.ts) files without converting the a Vue project using JSX into typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am working on a Vue 3 project which uses JSX. It is a component library which has components like Button, Tabs, Select, etc. All the components are javascript files with `.jsx` or `.tsx` extension like `Button.jsx`.

```
// src/Button.jsx
export default {
  props: ["text"],
  render() {
    return <button>{{ this.$props.text }}</button>
  }
}
```

Is there a way to create Typescript declaration `.d.ts` files without converting the whole project into typescript file? I'm new to Vue, so it may not make sense if you look.

I tried to declare the index.d.ts manually by importing the components and exporting them. But it doesn't work. Eg.

```
// index.d.ts
export Button from './src/Button.jsx';
```

I also included index.d.ts in `typings` field in package.json.

This clearly doesn't provide type support in IDE for the props like `text`.

Comment: You cannot magically generate the types out of a JavaScript file. If you want to keep using JavaScript, you need to manually write the type definition from scratch.

Comment: But what type definition should I write in `Button.d.ts` considering the above Button example.